# Infobright installation is unable to use mysql user

Tags: mysql, infobright

When trying to install Infobright, no matter what I try, it says it can't use the mysql-user.

If I try it with the dpkg -i infobright-4.0.7-0-i686-ice.deb, the log contains the following problems:

```
11:48:16 Installing infobright 4.0.7-0 (i686)
11:48:16 The installer will generate /tmp/ib4.0.7-0-install.log install trace log.
11:48:16 [step: pre (4.0.7-0, 1=upgrade)]
11:48:16 build type: static
11:48:19 [step: postun (4.0.7-0), 1=upgrade]
11:48:19 [step: post (4.0.7-0), 1=configure]
11:48:19 Install with RPM_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local, current prefix=/usr/local/infobright, prefix_actual=/usr/local/infobright-4.0.7-i686
11:48:19 upgrade=
11:48:19 Config file /etc/my-ib.cnf created
11:48:19 sed -e 's+@BH_PORT@+5029+' -e 's+@BH_BASEDIR@+/usr/local/infobright-4.0.7-i686+' -e 's+@BH_SOCK@+/tmp/mysql-ib.sock+' -e 's+@BH_DATADIR@+/usr/local/infobright-4.0.7-i686/data+' < /usr/local/infobright-4.0.7-i686/support-files/my-ib-master.cnf.in > /etc/my-ib-master.cnf
11:48:19 sed -e 's+@BH_PORT@+5029+' -e 's+@BH_BASEDIR@+/usr/local/infobright-4.0.7-i686+' -e 's+@BH_SOCK@+/tmp/mysql-ib.sock+' -e 's+@BH_DATADIR@+/usr/local/infobright-4.0.7-i686/data+' < /usr/local/infobright-4.0.7-i686/support-files/my-ib-slave.cnf.in > /etc/my-ib-slave.cnf
11:48:19 Creating/Updating datadir and cachedir
11:48:19 Creating user mysql and group mysql
groupadd: Gruppe »mysql« existiert bereits.
useradd: Benutzer »mysql« existiert bereits
usermod: Keine Änderungen
11:48:19 Installing default databases
140902 11:48:19 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ; Please check that the user exists! 

140902 11:48:19 [ERROR] Aborting

140902 11:48:19 [Note] /usr/local/infobright-4.0.7-i686/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

11:48:19 =============ERROR=======================
11:48:19 Failed on infobright initialization. You can investigate /tmp/ib4.0.7-0-install.log and log files from /usr/local/infobright-4.0.7-i686/data.
11:48:19 At this stage the current installation may be broken. You need to uninstall it and
11:48:19 fix the cause before retrying the installation.
11:48:19 Possible reasons for the failure are: LDAP service is running or
11:48:19 system has unsupported glibc but nscd service is not running.
11:48:19 Possible work arounds are: If LDAP is running, you may stop LDAP service prior to the installation.
11:48:19 If you have unsupported glibc, you need to start nscd service prior to the installation.
11:48:19 =========================================
```

Unforunately, something similiar happens when I try to install it from the tarball - everytime, the error `140902 11:48:19 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ; Please check that the user exists!` appears and the installation can't be finished.

In [Infobright startup error: Fatal error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199083/infobright-startup-error-fatal-error), someone seems to have a similiar error but does not realy pose the question. Does anyone know, how to solve this problem?

Another, unrelated error seems to be http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/linux/mysql/cant-change-to-run-as-user-mysql-please-check-that-the-user-exists/: Here, someone says I need to add the mysql-user. But I checked it, and the user exists an I am able to do something as this user. So unfortunately, I can't see any way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use CentOS 6.2 or higher, which  has a higher glibc version(2.12).

Compiling from source seems to be the only option. Tried that and got it working. We need to set

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/boost_1_42_0/lib
```

before running the command

```
bin/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/etc/my-ib.cnf --user=mysql
```

ICE Server is now up and running, and am able to login to the client as well. Only the `/etc/init.d/mysqd-ib` file is missing. Its very convenient to start and stop the server that way. Believe copying the file from another default installation should fix that. Will try that. Any suggestions in the meantime are welcome